# Old anime TV series with flying mechanical ships and dragons

Tags: story-identification, anime

There’s an anime series I watched in the late 90s on weekend kids TV in the UK that I can visualise but can't remember the name. It was the same time as *Sailor Moon* but not *Dragonball Z* or *Yu-gi-oh*.

I think it was another realm and was a fantasy/magic style story. There might be a flying mechanical ship and dragons. There was a powerful male lead (tall with brown hair) and a possible romance. I feel like it might have just been a one word title and was in English (not dubbed or subtitled).

I've checked programme listings for Cartoon Network and Fox Kids but can’t see it. It would have been on similar times to the X-men and Spider-Man cartoons back then.

Comment: Any other information about the anime ? for example what kind of magic are they using ? special weapons ? special events that happened ? the plot if you still remember it ? that would help in identifying the anime

Comment: the only name that comes to my mind is Uchuu Senkan Yamato

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're thinking of [*The Vision of Escaflowne*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vision_of_Escaflowne) from 1996.

[Trailer found here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vnP5Sxd49Y) Though it doesn't show it, I remember there were air ships in it.  The first episode involves a dragon, as its heart was used to power a mecha.

Comment: The main male character (Van) had black hair though, and wasn't particularly tall. Or maybe Louise was thinking of Allen, who was tall but had blond hair?

Comment: That's the one!! Thank you!